# Custom icons block in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-blocks

How do I create a custom block in Drupal 7 to show custom clickable icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Menu attributes module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes), and give the menu items IDs/Classes then style them using CSS.

Hope this works... Muhammad.